# Как передать значение переменной JS в переменную Java в Андроид

Tags: javascript, android, преобразование, совместимость

В Android проекте используется `RichEditor`, скриптом **JS** из него получаю значение которое заносится в `js-переменную`.

Необходимо преобразовать эту переменную с **JS** в **Java**.
Понимаю по логике что есть как минимум 2 варианта:

1) Методом **Java** получить доступ к `js-переменной` и получив ее значение присвоить `java-переменной`.

2) Выполнить **JS** скрипт в котором получаю доступ к `java-переменной` и передать ей значение из `js-переменной`.

Пробовал **ScriptEngineManage** - но в **AndroidStudio** он не работает.

Какими средствами это можно сделать в **AndroidStudio**?

Comment: Под "RichEditor" имелось ввиду: WYSIWYG текстовый редактор для Android. https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вопрос сводится к тривиальному взаимодействию JS из WebView с вашим Java-кодом.

[`RichEditor`](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android/blob/master/richeditor/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/richeditor/RichEditor.java#L39) это простой наследник `WebView`. Получить что-то из JS-кода в WebView можно разными способами, приведу примеры ниже.

---

- **Кастомный клиент**:

  Передаём значение:

  ```
  webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Hello World')");
  ```

  Получаем значение:

  ```
  final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

      // Также можно использовать и другой метод:
      // boolean onConsoleMessage (ConsoleMessage consoleMessage)

      @Override
      public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
          // message = 'Hello World'
          result.confirm();
          return true;
      }
  }
  ```

---

- **JavascriptInterface**

  Передаём значение:

  ```
  webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");
  webView.loadUrl("javascript:android.onData('Hello World!')");
  ```

  Получаем значение:

  ```
  @JavascriptInterface
  public void onData(String value) {
      // value = 'Hello World'
  }
  ```

---

[<sub>Вопрос на enSO</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298597/how-to-get-return-value-from-javascript-in-webview-of-android)

Comment: Отлично сработал 2-й вариант. Благодарю!